# Flutter redux: StoreConnector vs StoreProvider

Tags: flutter, redux, flutter-redux

I've been using flutter_redux for only very few days and I'm wondering what's the difference between:

```
class BtnCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final store = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context);

    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: store.dispatch(MyCustomAction),
      child: Text(store.state.MyCustomTxt),
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
class BtnCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => _ViewModel(
          txt: store.state.MyCustomTxt,
          onPressed: store.dispatch(MyCustomAction)),
      builder: (BuildContext context, _ViewModel vm) {
        return FlatButton(
          onPressed: vm.onPressed,
          child: Text(vm.txt),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ViewModel {
  final String txt;
  final void Function() onPressed;

  _ViewModel({this.txt, this.onPressed});
}
```

?

The first one seems so handy to use. Are they any advantages or drawbacks of using one over another I should be aware of?

According to the documentation, the StoreConnector will rebuild the widget in it so:

- Is it ok to not use a StoreConnector when you don't need to rebuild a widget?
- Is it ok to have multiple widgets within a StoreConnector?

Answer (score 7):

`StoreConnector` gives you more control over widget, especially when you don't want to rebuild it. `StoreConnector`:

- lets you detect whether the `ViewModel` has changed (whether widget should be rebuilt) if you use `distinct: true` and override `hashCode` and `==` in your `ViewModel`;
- lets you skip widget rebuild altogether by quickly checking some specific `store.state`:

  ```
   StoreConnector<AppState, MyViewModel>(
       distinct: true,
       ignoreChange: (state) {      
           return state.someVariable == theValueIDontCareAbout;
       },
       ...
   ),

   class MyViewModel{
       @override
       bool operator ==(other) {
            return (other is MyViewModel) && (this.someVmVariable == other.someVmVariable);
       }

       @override
       int get hashCode {
           int result = 17;
           result = 37 * result + someVmVariable.hashCode;
           return result;
       }
   }
  ```

And some more fine-grained controls. Take a look at the documentation of `StoreConnector`'s constructor. If multiple widgets inside store sonnector share the same ViewModel it is natural to have them like that. However, if it's possible to prevent them from rebulding by separating their `ViewModel`s you can use separate `StoreConnector`s.